# Exception failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

[Here you can also see the R.id error..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMXy3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its a very common error of Resource file.Import the your package name.R file in your class.